# How specify default a timezone for dates with a JsonSerializer?

Tags: c#, json, datetime, system.text.json

I am using using System.Text.Json to parse json data. Which contains a date filed without any time associated with it.  The parse does work and I get a datetime however the datetime is missing the time zone and the gateway which I am sending this to is rejecting it due to the lack of time zone.

I happen to know that the default time zone for this is infect  `GMT+2`  The issue is how to force it to add the time zone during the parse.

## Simple example for your testing pleasure.

I have a simple class with a date in it.

```
public class Testclass
{

    public DateTime RecordedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a Json string

```
 var json = "{ \"RecordedDate\": \"2017-11-22\"}";
```

Which I then try to parse.

```
  var response =  JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Testclass>(json);
```

The parse does work however it does not contain a Timezone is there a way to specify the default timezone?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `DateTimeConvertor` and handle the conversion as per your need.

```
public class DateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString()), DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {          
        writer.WriteStringValue(DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Utc));
    }
}
```

Use the Convertor during serializing/deserializing.

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();

options.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());

var response = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Testclass>(json, options);

var responseJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(response, options);
```

The `responseJson` will have datetime in the desired format.

Comment: Check for `DateTime.Kind` property after deserialization.

Comment: This works like a charm.   I just need to figure out how to specify a specific time zone.

Comment: you are probably looking for `DateTimeOffset` ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=net-5.0. because `DateTime` doesn't have TimeZone Info

Comment: This worked but i think we are going to end up fixing it on the the other end.  The system sending it to me needs to start sending the time zone offset or i am going to loose my mind with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is by default.

As far as I know, timezone conversion should *not* be handled while on deserialization (or serialization) process. These topics should be separated in my opinion.

If I were you, I would use [`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime?view=net-5.0) method (or similar ones) after I get `DateTime` in your process. This of course, *might* depend the logic of your code.

You might wanna check;

- [DateTime and DateTimeOffset support in System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/system-text-json-support)

On the other hand, [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) supports [`DateTimeZoneHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDateTimeZoneHandling.htm) which probably you can use on deserialize as well.

Comment: unfortunately when the dates are parsed they parse as 2020-12-21T00:00:00 and the gate way i am sending them to responds with a message stating that there must be a time zone attached.   If I manually add a Z it works.   So basically i need a way of forcing the Z on the end i guess.